# How to pass or reference $index in the controller

Tags: angularjs

In the view (html file) I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in ctrl.model.unplannedTasks">
   <td>{{::$index + 1}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I reference `$index + 1` value in my controller?

I have tried doing this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in ctrl.model.unplannedTasks" ng-init="myIndex =   $index + 1">
   <td ng-model = "myIndex">{{myIndex}}</td>
</tr>
```

And then reference it in the controller with `myIndex`, but it is `undefined`.

[EDIT]
`$index + 1` is the row number in the table. I would like to reference a current value of the specific row in order to be able to put it in the message like:
Are you sure you want to delete row e.g. 5?  (this message is generated inside the controller)

Comment: But you have more than one `$index` variable. Do you need an array of `$index` ?

Comment: In what context do you need to reference this `myIndex`? Do you want to call a function with this parameter? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @New Dev I have edited my question, so please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In controller if it is use as value or otherwise use as array:

```
angular.module('rock').controller('test',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.myIndex=0;
$scope.unplannedTasks="you can define your object here";
}]);

In view:
<tr ng-repeat="task in unplannedTasks">
   <td myIndex={{::$index + 1}}></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to pass it as it is `$index+1` to the function in which the message is generated.

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in ctrl.model.unplannedTasks">
<td>{{::$index + 1}}</td>
</tr>  
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="ctrl.openModal(task, $index + 1)" title="{{::msg.common.button.remove}}">{{::msg.common.button.remove}}</button>
```

Comment: Check this link:you can pass row index to your controller http://plnkr.co/edit/i1v8rJw7huS4c789Z3Ev?p=preview